# Keyof different behavior using constructor assignment

Tags: typescript, constructor, keyof

I'm experiencing a different behavior of the "keyof" using the constructor assignement...

[Here is the code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20Class1%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(private%20a%3A%20number%2C%20private%20b%3A%20string)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20method1()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(%22method1%22)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Class2%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20a%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20b%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20method1()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(%22method1%22)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Cet1Props%20%3D%20keyof%20Class1%3B%20%2F%2F%20%22method1%22%0D%0Atype%20Class2Props%20%3D%20keyof%20Class2%3B%20%2F%2F%20%22a%22%20%7C%20%22b%22%20%7C%20%22method1%22%0D%0A)

```
class Class1 {
constructor(private a: number, private b: string) {
}
method1() {
    console.log("method1");
    }
}

class Class2 {
    a: number;
    b: string;
    constructor() {
    }
    method1() {
        console.log("method1");
    }
}

type Cet1Props = keyof Class1; // "method1"
type Class2Props = keyof Class2; // "a" | "b" | "method1"
```

I can't understand why is it so, can someone explain me?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Class2` they are public (which is the default), wheras in `Class1` they are private.

To make them comparable (i.e. to prove it is nothing to do with the constructor assignment) add the private access modifier to `Class2` (or change `Class1` to make them `public`).

```
class Class2 {
    private a: number;
    private b: string;

    constructor() {
    }

    method1() {
        console.log("method1");
    }
}
```

If the `a` and `b` members are private, you'll get:

```
type Class2Props = keyof Class2;  // "method1"
```